# The "All Actions" tab is a violation of my privacy

Tags: support, privacy, activity-tab, last-activity

It's been brought to my attention that I am spending a lot of time on Stack Overflow and not purely performing research but actually spending time answering questions and commenting!

I asked how they knew —"looking at your profile **all your actions** are visible to the world"!

I feel this is an invasion of privacy. I am happy for managers, colleagues, friends and Stack Overflow users to know when I was last on the site, but I don't want them auditing what I do apart from seeing Q & A's that I participate on.

**Desired solution:**

An opt-out option of your "All Actions" profile tab being shown to users with < 750 points.

Comment: Is there something like Godwin's law but for the NSA? Because I have an itching feeling someone else is going to start something on about that in the comments...

Comment: Have you considered not associating your real name with public activity that you don't want your real name associated with?  Seems obvious.

Comment: Even if you could opt out of your actions being shown on your profile, they'd still be a part of [sede](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).  I doubt SO will anonymize their data dumps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even if that tab were removed, the actions displayed in it *are actually public* - the answers you post are visible to one and all, your name and the time you posted prominently displayed below them.

No sense in trying to be sly about it... Take pride in your work!